# Search multiple file names from the database VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

My problem is that I'm trying to get all file names from the data base, but this only works if I write specifically the file names, for example, in my db I have a column named "File" and it's only the name of the file without any extension so I call the variable "file_name" and add the extension but doesn't seem to work...

Here is the table:

```
   Id   |      Court     |    File   |      Email    
--------+----------------+-----------+-----------------  
   1    | COURT NUMBER 1 | DocumentA | John@email.com 
   2    | COURT NUMBER 1 | DocumentB | Judy@email.com   
   3    | COURT NUMBER 1 | DocumentC | Edgar@email.com   
   4    | COURT NUMBER 1 | DocumentD | Brit@email.com
```

And here is the code:

```
If (Court.ToUpper.Trim = "COURT NUMER 1") Then
    Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("\\192.168.1.70\SisInt\Court\Agreements\J102016SEM" & semester)

    For Each fi In di.GetFiles(file_name.Trim + "docx")
        If fi.Extension.ToUpper = ".DOC" Or fi.Extension.ToUpper = ".DOCX" Then
            FileList.Add(fi.FullName)
            NameList.Add((fi.Name.Substring(0, fi.Name.Length - fi.Extension.Length)))
        End If
    Next
End If
```

But this only works if I write exactly the name of one file with the extension (doesn't work if I put more than one file name)

```
For Each fi In di.GetFiles("DocumentA.docx")
```

So, any idea how to call all the file names from the datebase at once?

Comment: Can you explain how a database plays into this?  That code is just looking for files on disk - is that where they are actually stored and just the filename is in the DB?

Comment: ...also where/how is the db data located in your app?  `Court` and `file_name` look like variables which can only be one file at a time.  Where are the rest?

Comment: Yeah, the code is searching for the files in a remote folder and the filename is just stored in the DB

Comment: `...also where/how is the db data located in your app?`

Comment: I did a query where I'm getting the variables Court and file_name

Comment: Well if you want `all the file names from the datebase at once` you need all the filename from the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your search pattern to this:

```vb
di.GetFiles(file_name.Trim + ".doc*")
```

And you can get the file name without the extension in an easier way:

```vb
NameList.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name))
```